# How to launch a container on every boot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

Am running jenkins container on my ubuntu bionic laptop.

It is initially launched using command `docker-compose up -d`

On every boot, the container status goes in Exited state:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
479a1bec5451        docker-jenkins_jenkins   "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   12 hours ago        Exited (143) 10 hours ago                       docker-jenkins_jenkins_1
```

---

Given local workspace of jenkins dockerfile in my machine:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 371 Nov 23 08:40 docker-compose.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2578 Nov 23 19:52 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1148 Nov  6 10:33 plugins.txt
```

Below is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  jenkins_home:
    external: true

services:
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        DOCKER_GID: ${DOCKER_GID}
        DOCKER_VERSION: ${DOCKER_VERSION}
        DOCKER_COMPOSE: ${DOCKER_COMPOSE}
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

---

Would like to launch this jenkins container on single instance ECS cluster.

How to ensure docker container is in `Up` status on every boot?

Comment: Did you try adding restart: always in your docker-compose.yml file?

Answer (score 1):

```
restart: always
```

Or

```
restart: unless-stopped
```

in your docker-compose.yml

check: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart